# Stop notepad from opening multiple same instances

Tags: notepad

How do I open only one instance of the same text file using Windows Notepad (Not Notepad++)? 
For example right now if I open my `notes.txt`, it opens an instance, but if I click and open the same `notes.txt` again, it opens another same instance thus having two same files left opened. This causes confusion when it comes to saving my work sometime.
How do I resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: So far i know, the default Windows Notepad doesn't have such a function. I would  recommend a tool like Notepad++ or Ultra-Edit. For example Ultra-Edit will notify you about changes to any open files and offer to reload the latest Version.

Comment: The new notepad open the same file just in a new tab instead in the same, problem here

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 and 10 you can create a shortcut to the txt file and it will go to the open Notepad window for that file instead of opening a second instance.

Sadly as of Windows 11 this no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Open Notepad.  To the right is a gear icon for settings.  Once you've clicked the gear icon, click on "When Notepad starts".  Choose "Open a new window".

Thank you!